# Could the "verilog-a" tag be created?

Tags: feature-request

I don't have 300 rep yet on this website. A `verilog-a` (and maybe as well a `Verilog-AMS`) tag would be useful for a few questions, in my opinion.

Comment: How would it help to differentiate `verilog-a` and `verilog-AMS` from each other and other `verilog` questions?

Comment: well verilog-a is a subset of verilog-ams so it would make more sense to have a verilog-ams tag instead

Comment: @brhans, there is no `verilog-AMS` tag for now, as far as I'm aware of. Also, @JonRb, as a subset of verilog-AMS, verilog-AMS answers wouldn't really help verilog-a-related questions. I concede that both would probably be quite a niche tag, though.

Comment: Please point out those questions, then we can create the tag.

Comment: Well, here is one that I asked: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386591/how-to-model-electric-power-consumption-in-verilog-a (I was a bit dissatisfied with the answer, and got sidetracked later, I'll think of accepting it). Verilog-a is quite a different beast: you can input differential constraints between various signals, and not only handle discrete voltage levels, but flux (intensity, charges) as well, and in "analog"/floating point. Syntax is a bit different, and they are not directly compatible with each other, a bit like systemverilog, although that is a superset.

Comment: Here are more: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117752/contribution-statements-in-verilog-a https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378070/diode-modeling-in-verilog-a https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24315/what-fpga-chips-support-verilog-ams-or-verilog-a https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/free-veriloga-simulators/156766 I can edit my question to point these and more if necessary.